# Extracting URLs from string Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a free form text field on the application for URLs. There is no fixed format so I am struggling to extract the URLs from the text. There can be multiple URLs embedded in the text. How do I extract them individually? Thanks!

*Example*

```
<p><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:calibri"> Final Rule: <u><span style="color:blue"><a href="https://www.google.com/rules/final/2011/33-10345.pdf"><span style="color:blue">Disclosure</span></a></span></u></span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:calibri">Press Release: <span style="color:blue"><a href="https://www.co.gov/news/press-release"><span style="color:blue">Hedging Policies</span></a></span></span></span></p>
```

Comment: Parsing data out of HTML isn't generally very pleasant. You can maybe use a regular expression is you can define a safe pattern - e.g. if it's always enclosed in (double?) quotes, and/or is always an `href`, etc. You've tagged this with PL/SQL - how is the free-form text/HTML getting to you; are you seeing it from a table, as a procedure argument, a bind variable? What will you do with the extracted URLs - what form will the result of this extraction take?

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for the response. I am seeing the data from a table and the need is to use it in a report that will display the URLs as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'a href="(.*?)"',1,level,null,1) as url
   from t
connect by level<=REGEXP_COUNT(col,'a href="(.*?)"')
and prior id = id                 --add these 2 lines to extract from multiple
and prior sys_guid() is not null; --rows in a table where id is the primary key.
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d4920bddd38ff1c932b2a9fbc4c7b2a)

Comment: Thank you @kaushik! This is very helpful but taking forever to extract from my table despite having some filters. Is there a way to have this as a function and return as a csv field if there are multiple URLs?

Comment: @Cindy : So, you are running this on a whole table? You didn't tell us. Does your table have a unique id/primary key column? Also confirm if there is only one url in a column's text or multiple entries per row?

Comment: yes I am. The table does have a primary key. There can be multiple URLs in the column's text but its only 1 row per ID.

Comment: thanks so much, this works!! However the performance is pretty bad.